# About getting random values between fixed range in java

Tags: java

the thing I wanted to know is that. Example: I want range of number from 1 to 10. and how to call a random number between the range from 1 to 10 automatically. Not using switches cases or if else statements. Any Idea ?

Comment: Do you know how hava UUID looks like?

Comment: ahh.. 128 bit value. Example: 48baf78c-3263-42eb-856d-618dd636aa46

Comment: That being said, why do you need to have it between fixed range?

Comment: Sir, Is there anything that could be used that could have fixed range and when we call it, it should return random numbers between that fixed range.

Comment: As far as I know no, you might need to implement your own generator. Check the grep code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/UUID.java#UUID.randomUUID%28%29

Comment: Is there any other class or method except UUID ? Can I use Random ?

Comment: So, what do you want to achieve? Be clear on that, you first said you want UUID between some ranges, now you are asking me about random. Write clearly the use-case, otherwise me or someone will mark it as not-clear question

Comment: Sorry sir. Okay, the thing I wanted to know is that.
Example: I want range of number from 1 to 10. and how to call a random number between the range from 1 to 10 automatically. Not using switches cases or if else statements. Any Idea ?

Comment: Edit your question accordingly please.

Comment: @BibeshManandhar If you want to know how to get a random value between two values: [Generating random integers in a specific range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-specific-range)